# Need to add a default value to a returned SQL SELECT queried list

Tags: sql, select, kentico-13

We have a Kentico 13 page type field with a Drop-down list form control that queries a db table to populate the list.

Currently, the list pre-selects the top value, but this won't work because it's not a required field, so I'm wondering if there's a way to add a default "Select one" value to the dropdown list.

**Things to note:**

- To be clear, I don't need to add a default value to the table.
- I also have no further control over this dropdown list, so the default has to be added in the SQL query itself.

**Below, is the original query that returns the appropriate list. The only thing that's missing is a default value.**

`SELECT t.NodeGUID, t.DocumentName FROM VIEW_CMS_TREE_JOINED t WHERE t.ClassName = 'AscediaRedesign.Industry' ORDER BY t.DocumentName`

Below is a screenshot of how we set up the page type field (using the above SQL query), followed by another screenshot of the successfully populated dropdown list:
[image]

[image]

**A member of the Kentico community suggested trying a UNION, but I was unable to get this to work:**

`SELECT '' as NodeGUID, 'Please Select' as DocumentName UNION SELECT t.NodeGuid, t.DocumentName FROM VIEW_CMS_TREE_JOINED t WHERE t.ClassName = 'AscediaRedesign.Industry'`

The above query results in this error: "Caused exception: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

Comment: Maybe `SELECT NULL as NodeGUID`? And make this `UNION ALL`, as there are no duplicates to remove.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Wow, yes that was the issue. I really overlooked that one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below queries. Blank is not valid GUID. That is the reason for the error.

```
SELECT NEWID() as NodeGUID, 
       'Please Select' as DocumentName 
 UNION ALL 
SELECT t.NodeGuid, 
       t.DocumentName 
  FROM VIEW_CMS_TREE_JOINED t 
 WHERE t.ClassName = 'AscediaRedesign.Industry'
```

or

```
SELECT NULL as NodeGUID, 
       'Please Select' as DocumentName 
 UNION ALL 
SELECT t.NodeGuid, 
       t.DocumentName 
  FROM VIEW_CMS_TREE_JOINED t 
 WHERE t.ClassName = 'AscediaRedesign.Industry'
```